# can I filter columns based in a dataframe based on schema in databricks scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, databricks

I have a `dataframe` which has 7 columns (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`)

```
df.schema // output
StructType(
  StructField(A,StringType,true), 
  StructField(B,StringType,true), 
  StructField(C,true), 
  StructField(D,true), 
  StructField(E,StringType,true), 
  StructField(F,StringType,true), 
  StructField(G,true)
)
```

Is there any way, I can filter the columns of a dataframe by using another schema as below

```
val newSchema = StructType(
  StructField(A,StringType,true), 
  StructField(B,StringType,true), 
  StructField(C,StringType,true)
)
```

At the end,  I would like to select columns `A`, `B`, `C` from dataframe `df` using `newSchema`
Please suggest possible ways

Comment: maybe something like: `df.select(newSchema.fields.map(_.name):_*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val cols = newSchema.fields.map(_.name)

display(df.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)

This is working